# SqlException not being caught

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have an ASP.Net application with the following code:

> ```
>     try
>     {
>         sql = new SqlProc("prcCustomerAgeSelect",
>             SqlProc.InParam("@DateFrom", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8, _OrderDateFrom),
>             SqlProc.InParam("@DateTo", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8, _OrderDateTo),
>         sql.Command.CommandTimeout = 1;
>         dt = sql.ExecuteTable();
>
>     }
>     catch (SqlException ex)
>     {
>         Filter.ErrorMessage = "Please narrow your search criteria.";
>     }
> ```

Note the line:

> sql.Command.CommandTimeout = 1;

Which causes a SqlException to be thrown (for testing).

I would have thought that the catch block would catch this exception, but it doesn't. Instead, I get:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]

Why doesn't it catch it?? Am I using the wrong type? What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!!

-Ev

Comment: Please post your *real* code, the code you have up there does not compile and we can't make an accurate assessment of what is going on without accurate code.

Comment: What is the output of `Console.WriteLine(ex.GetType().Name)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like what you're seeing isn't a `SqlException`.

It's possible that `SqlProc` is itself catching `SqlExceptions`, extracting some information from them, then throwing new exceptions of a different type (embedding some of the original info in the new exception's message).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Although I don't think that's the case because the exeception thrown to the browser is:
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Comment: So, I take that to mean that the exception is of type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, which is exactly what I'm trying to catch. Right?

Comment: Nope - I stand corrected. The SqlException was being wrapped with an ApplicationException (for some reason):                 throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Unexpected error executing: {0}", GetProcDebugString(cmd)), ex);

Comment: And you were right, it was SqlProc doing it. The question remains, why did the Exception on screen say it was an exception of type SqlExecption, when it was really an ApplicationException?

Comment: @Ev: `ApplicationException` has very likely overridden `ToString()`

Comment: @Ev - you're mighty welcome! This illustrates why it's rarely a good idea to catch `Exceptions` in library code (like the `SqlProc` class) when it isn't possible to do anything useful with them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it may be a connection timeout, rather than a command timeout.

I would check to make sure that you can connect and run the query with a more sensible timeout value just to verify this.